# Handle a lot of Futures given by asynchronous rest-requests

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, jersey

I wanna use the jersey-client for creating asynchronous rest-requests, the function delivers me Futures, so i can, in my understanding, invoke get, and if the request is finished it will return something.

So i am thinking, i could store the Futures in a map and look into them from time to time by one thread. Or maybe i should create a new thread everytime someone sending an asynchronous request. There is also a requirement that it shouldn't last forever (a timeout).

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I often use a `List<Future<Void>>` to store the futures. As `get()` blocks, I just cycle through them rather than poll them.

> There is also a requirement that it should last forever (a timeout).

I assume you mean its *shouldn't* last forever.  This requires support in the library you are using to make the requests.  If they can be interrupted you can cancel(true) the future either in your waiting thread or another ScheduledExecutorService. If they can't be interrupts you may have to stop() the thread but *only as a last resort*.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) says:

> A Future represents the result of an asynchronous computation. Methods
>   are provided to check if the computation is complete, to wait for its
>   completion, and to retrieve the result of the computation. The result
>   can only be retrieved using method get when the computation has
>   completed, blocking if necessary until it is ready.

Therefore it is up to you to choose which strategy to adopt: it mostly depends on what you want to do with those requests.

You could place those `Future`s in any iterable structure before going through them. Block on each `get` may be a strategy if you can handle each result pretty fast and do need to check while waiting if other futures are already returned.